# Issue generating a PDF file using PHP

Tags: php, pdf

I am trying to generate a PDF report from my expense table in my database but keep getting the error:

```
Warning: mysqli_query() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli, null given on line 79
Error: 
Query: SELECT * from expenses

function Table($query,$prop=array())
{
    //Issue query
    LINE 79 =   $res=mysqli_query($db_connection, $query) or die('Error: '.mysql_error()."<BR>Query: $query");
    //Add all columns if none was specified
    if(count($this->aCols)==0)
    {
        $nb=mysql_num_fields($res);
        for($i=0;$i<$nb;$i++)
            $this->AddCol();
    }
```

---

other PHP file
        //Connect to database
    include("connect.php");
    //mysql_connect('localhost','root','');
    //mysql_select_db('classicmodels');

```
$pdf=new PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();
//First table: put all columns automatically
$pdf->Table('SELECT * from expenses');
$pdf->AddPage();
//Second table: specify 3 columns
$pdf->AddCol('id',40,'','C');
$pdf->AddCol('user_id',40,'expenses','C');
$pdf->AddCol('currency',40,'type','C');
$prop=array('HeaderColor'=>array(255,150,100),
            'color1'=>array(210,245,255),
            'color2'=>array(255,255,210),
            'padding'=>2);
$pdf->Table('select user_id,  amount, currency from expenses order by id limit 0,10',$prop);
```

Comment: `$db_connection` doesn't exist in the scope of your `Table()` function

Comment: isnt it needed for database connection in sqli?

Comment: It's needed if you're using MySQLi in a procedural style, as you are

Comment: $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE id = '$userID'";
$result = mysqli_query($db_connection, $query);

while ($dbRow = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) something like this?

Comment: As @MarkBaker noted, `$db_connection` doesn't exist when you get to the `Table` function. I'm sure it's declared somewhere, but if it's outside the `{ }` that make up the `Table` function, then code inside that function can't "see" it. Check out [this link](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

Comment: db_connection is declared in my database connect file $db_connection = mysqli_connect("$db_location","$db_username","$db_password","$db_database") which is at the beginning of the script as include("connect.php");

Comment: The beginning of the script !== in the Table() function

Comment: I'm now receiving Warning: fopen(.pdf): failed to open stream: Permission denied on line 1025
FPDF error: Unable to create output file: .pdf   ...error line case 'F':
   // Save to local file
   $f = fopen($name,'wb');
   if(!$f)
    $this->Error('Unable to create output file: '.$name);
   fwrite($f,$this->buffer,strlen($this->buffer));
   fclose($f);
   break;